# Check if folder is already open in os explorer (JAVA)

Tags: java, directory, explorer

In my desktop application facilitates user to download one or more files. The application will facilitate user to select the location of the folder in which the download will be saved and the application will save the downloaded file in the selected folder. When user download a file in the same folder of a previous download and he has not close the explorer window yet, the system should not to reopen the folder.

Summarizing:

I open the folder in the first download:

> desktop.open(dirToOpen);

But if this folder is already open, if the user selects one more download, I want to display nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with Java (I could be wrong). But from Windows Programming, you may be able to find out the list of open folders in explorer and see if your dir is there. Can you see if similar API is there for Java as well?

Comment: So after the user downloaded the first file and then he downloads another file and selects the same output directory then you don't want to open a 2nd Explorer window? `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open();` does exactly that.

Comment: The `Desktop.open(...)` functionality is platform dependent, so in theory it *could* just bring the window with the already opened folder to the front, instead of re-opening. But as you ask, I guess it's not implemented that way. If possible through native APIs, you could use JNA to do whatever you like.

Comment: Dear haraldK and mrt

It's true. Now it works!

I don't know if It was an stupid confusion or I the build project was working with previous solution which I had applied (with the runtime).

But the important is that Desktop works fine.